# Count(distinct) with multiple fields in django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

Here I trying to convert Django rawsql query to Django queryset.

But the problem is - how to implement distinct in two columns?

SQL query:

```
count(distinct ra, category) as order_type
```

Django queryset - order_type=Count('ra', 'category', distinct=True) - this is causing an error.

```
queryset = Model.objects.raw("select id,category,count(category) 
as total_orders, count(distinct ra, category) as order_type, 
SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_success_order, 
SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_failed_order 
from table 
group by ra;")


queryset = Model.objects.values('ra').annotate(category=F('category'),\
order_type=Count('ra', 'category', distinct=True),total_orders=Count('category'),\
total_success_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='success')),\
total_failed_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='failed'))).order_by()
```

What should be the right syntax?

Data-

```
category   ra   service_status
cat1       11      success
cat1       12      success
cat2       11      success
cat2       11      success
cat1       15      success
cat3       5       failed
```

ra 11 should be returned as `order_type = 2` (i.e, if same ra is with two different category)

O/p-

```
Category  order type   total order   successful  failed
 cat1        1            10              5         5
 cat2        2            14              10       4
 cat3        1            9               9        0
```

Comment: Since you `GROUP BY ra`, you can eiliminate `ra` out of the `Count`, so `Count('category', distinct=True)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then not giving required results

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Let me put the case in above

Comment: @Iceman Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 7):

> Bit late, Hope this helps someone.

**You can use Django Database Function [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/):**

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = Model.objects.values('ra').annotate(order_type=Count(Concat('ra', 'category'), distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Django QuerySet [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) takes optional `*fields` parameters.  So you can write:

```py
Model.objects.distinct('ra', 'category').count()
```